# Stopping People Viewing Draft Posts

Tags: customization, posts

At any one time I have a number of blog articles that are in draft. Generally, if I encounter something useful, I'll note it in a draft blog entry, to revisit, research and write up at a later date.

So, while these aren't accessible from any hyperlink, I find I am still able to reference them by going to the link directly. E.g: http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/?p=xxxx (where 'xxxx' is the post number).

Recently, on my site logs, I have seen an IP (from Ljubljana, Slovenia) that has been accessing these draft posts, which although not particularly sensitive, is still kind-of annoying. I'm guessing they are using the method above.

Is there any way of stopping this?

**EDIT**:

Given the response below, I am indeed unable to access the post when logged out, however I am still seeing from my access logs hits on my draft pages.

Any more thoughts?

Comment: To answer the updated question:
What plugin shows that? and information is shown? is it the page data? or just URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you (read: the logged in user) will be able to see the drafted post. But, a guest will not be able to read it.

To test it, login to one browser and create a draft. See its URL in another browser where you don't login (no cookie, etc).

Comment: The Google Chrome "Incognito" (private browsing) mode is very handy for this sort of testing, since you can create a fresh, logged out browser window without losing your other session or switching applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I'm still seeing accesses on my draft posts from this IP. Any thoughts?

Comment: my best bet is, they will only see 404 (just like you when accessing draft post as guest) on that post.

Comment: Just because an IP *requests* a resource from a URL doesn't mean they'll get it back.  So these site logs are just showing that someone tried to view your post ... but without logging in they couldn't actually see them.  A better question would be *why* is someone at this IP trying to see your draft posts in the first place?